# Maven: how to remove local overriding class and compile with the original class in a dependency when shade package the project to a jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, ant, maven-shade-plugin

I create a class A with the same name and package as B in the spark lib to override B when I run a spark program locally, so as to help me debug the program.

I also need to shade package the program to a jar with dependencies to upload to a server to run the spark program in a cluster.

The problem is, every time I shade package the program, I need to remove the locally defined class A first, otherwise, when I run the shade packaged jar in the cluster, an exception would fail the whole process:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: A.fun1.
```

And next time I need to debug the program locally I need to add back the class A again. This is a bit annoying.

I wonder if Maven can help me remove the local overriding class A and compile with the original class B when shape package the project, while still enable me to run and debug the program locally with local class A overriding class B in spark.

FYI:

1. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and maven 3.
2. Class A defined locally and Class B in the spark lib have exactly the same class name, package name, function names and parameters.
3. I tried this and it did not work:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.3</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>uber-jar</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>shade</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
                       <filters>
                           <filter>
                               <artifact>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</artifact>
                               <excludes>
                                   <exclude>package-of-classA/classA.*</include>
                               </excludes>
                           </filter>
                       </filters>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```

   and reports:

> "User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: A.fun1."

Comment: Can you explain why you have this local overriding class? Sounds wrong to me...

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to override a class in spark to read mock data in my local file storage instead of a remote hadoop cluster. I override the class in spark so as to avoid modifying the program code when I do the local debug and remote package submission.